# Connection to MSSQL from PHP 5.2.9

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm trying to connect a php application with Microsoft SQL Server and It fails!!!

---

**Technical Context:**

- Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard.
- XAMPP Server v1.7.1:

  - Apache v2.2.11.
  - PHP 5.2.9.
- Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (Express Edition).
- Microsoft .NET Framework v4.0.20219.42000.

---

**Problem Summary:**

- Apparently, the mssql driver is OK! I checked if the folder "...\xampp\php\ext\" has "php_mssql.dll" and if there are a reference with it in php.ini file... and yes!!! Everything is Ok!
- I don't have any authentication problem in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (I'm using a SQL Server Authentication and Windows Authentication).
- I have problems in a simple PHP Connection (I'm using the sames authentication data of Management Studio). Where I added the following:

$link = mssql_connect('SERVERNAME\SQLEXPRESS','username','password');

But, the web browser answer is "mssql_connect() [function.mssql-connect]: Unable to connect to server:  SERVERNAME\SQLEXPRESS".

- I checked the port and it isn't the default one. It's using another. So, I tried putting the port and I got the same error.

  - I tried with all of these severname combinations (using username/password in the connection and not using) (What's the correct one?):
  - SEVERNAME
  - SEVERNAME\SQLEXPRESS
  - SEVERNAME\SQLEXPRESS
  - SEVERNAME\SQLEXPRESS,PORT
  - SEVERNAME\SQLEXPRESS,PORT
  - SEVERNAME,PORT\SQLEXPRESS
  - SEVERNAME,PORT\SQLEXPRESS
  - SEVERNAME,PORT
  - localhost
  - localhost\SQLEXPRESS
  - localhost\SQLEXPRESS
  - localhost\SQLEXPRESS,PORT
  - localhost\SQLEXPRESS,PORT
  - localhost,PORT\SQLEXPRESS
  - localhost,PORT\SQLEXPRESS
  - localhost,PORT
  - 127.0.0.1
  - 127.0.0.1\SQLEXPRESS
  - 127.0.0.1\SQLEXPRESS
  - 127.0.0.1\SQLEXPRESS,PORT
  - 127.0.0.1\SQLEXPRESS,PORT
  - 127.0.0.1,PORT\SQLEXPRESS
  - 127.0.0.1,PORT\SQLEXPRESS
  - 127.0.0.1,PORT
  - LOCALIP
  - LOCALIP\SQLEXPRESS
  - LOCALIP\SQLEXPRESS
  - LOCALIP\SQLEXPRESS,PORT
  - LOCALIP\SQLEXPRESS,PORT
  - LOCALIP,PORT\SQLEXPRESS
  - LOCALIP,PORT\SQLEXPRESS
  - LOCALIP,PORT

It's important to say: this machine is a testing server! I could connect the application with a sql server in a development machine. So, I tried to connect the development machine application with the testing machine database server and I got the same error. The unique technical differences between the testing and development machines are in the development machine I'm using SQL SERVER 2016 and Windows 10.

What is it could be the problem? Thanks!

Comment: There hasn't been a PHP 5.2 release in 6 years. And you're not even using the latest 5.2 release. First thing you need to do is upgrade to at least 5.6 which is in active support until tomorrow. I'd recommend 7.0 though. This will not fix your problem but it will ensure you're using software from this decade.

Comment: Have you checked the "Allow remote connections" setting? Also check the TCP connection configuration in SQL Server, and, finally, check any firewalls for blocking on the ports used by the SQL Server

Comment: @LaughingVergil The solution was set the filestream properties (in Sql Server Configuration Manager -> SQL Server Services -> Right click on SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) -> Properties -> FILESTREAM), enabling filestream for Transact-SQL and file IO accesses and allowing remote clients access to FILESTREAM data.

Comment: @miken32 The solution was set the filestream properties (in Sql Server Configuration Manager -> SQL Server Services -> Right click on SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) -> Properties -> FILESTREAM), enabling filestream for Transact-SQL and file IO accesses and allowing remote clients access to FILESTREAM data.

Comment: You're still using 10 year old software. Good luck!

Comment: @miken32 I'm using a very old PHP version because I'm supporting an old application developed on a old PHP Framework Kohana version (2.3.4). This version works with a very old php driver that is compatibly with PHP < 5.3. Believe me, all this is a very headache!

After this solution, I got new erros! If you want to help me, you are invited: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453138/php-spend-long-time-connecting-to-mssql-and-never-connect